# How to get a random seed from /dev/urandom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, random, seed

In python 3.11 and ubuntu 22.04 I am trying to get a random **seed** (as opposed to a random number from a seeded system).  I have a system running a process that is looping. At various points in the loop I set all python and system RNG settings to specific seeds for repeatability.  At a particular point I need a random seed, separate from the specific seeds used for the system.

The random seed I need is an integer with the upper range of (2^32 -1).  Yes there is a function, but it returns a value from the seeded system.

I have a hardware RNG in a USB port that works with the rng5-tools package, but I cannot access it directly.  I assume it is used to fill the entropy pool and that os.urandom() pulls bits from that pool.

I tried using os.urandom() to generate an integer, then take the last character of that integer.  The distribution of the ten individual characters (0 thru 9) is uniform.  I have run samples of 10^3 to 10^7 to verify this.

I do this 10 times, each time adding the single character to a string, then convert the string to an integer.  Each time I add an integer to the string, I right-pad it with zeros and test if it is < 4294967296 (2^32 -1).  If it fails, the character is discarded and a new character is obtained and tested until it passes the test. If it succeeds I keep it in the string and repeat the process for new characters until a total of ten-characters are obtained.  I then convert the string to an integer.

However the distribution of the resulting integers is skewed as shown in the graph.  Can anyone shed any light as to why?  The code is:

```
def gen_seed(digits = 10): 

  ssc = ""
  for i in range(digits):
    found_digit = False
    while found_digit == False:
    
      rand=f"{int.from_bytes(os.urandom(1), sys.byteorder)}"
      digit = f"{rand[-1]}"

      ssc_test = int(f"{ssc}{digit}".ljust(10,"0"))

      if ssc_test < 4294967296:
        found_digit = True
        ssc = f"{ssc}{digit}"
  ss = int(ssc)
  return(ss)
```

[image: Resulting ten-digit integer frequency]

Comment: One common approach is to take the low-order part of the current time.

Comment: @ScottHunter Two consecutive calls to time.time() may return the same value

Comment: the bias is because you're keeping the "found digits" rather than starting from scratch every time.  the probability of picking a `4` in the first round is 1/4 but it should be a third of that.  hence the histogram jumps by `1e9 / (2**32 % 1e9)`

Comment: Hi Sam, picking a 4 on the first round is actually a 1 in 5 chance (0 - 4).  I am not seeing why a uniform dist of 10 different digits on the first character, from which half of them are discarded, should lean toward the particular number 4?

Comment: @DarkKnight: How is that relevant to taking the fastest-changing part of a *single* time?

Comment: @betacrash 1/5th is right, sorry.  digits 0 to 3 have 1e9 possible values, while 4 only has ~3e8 values.  the values under 4 are therefore "squished up" and hence show up with higher counts in the histogram

Comment: "The random seed I need is an integer with the upper range of (2^32 -1). Yes there is a function, but it returns a value from the seeded system." - Hint: how many bytes does it take, in order to represent an unsigned integer with that range? If you have that many bytes, interpreted as an unsigned integer, can they represent any integers outside that range? (Hint for the hint: why do you suppose the API specifies this particular limit?) Knowing these facts, can you think of a simple way to get the random integer you need, using a **single** call to `os.urandom`?

Comment: " I am not seeing why a uniform dist of 10 different digits on the first character, from which half of them are discarded, should lean toward the particular number 4?" - then you have a question about probability (and perhaps about basic mathematical reasoning), not a question about programming. Just to make sure: you don't understand why, if your function will 20% of the time decide that the final value of `ssc` should start with a 4, but that value should **only actually** start with a 4 about 6.87% of the time, the output is biased?

Comment: (Or perhaps you don't understand why the value should only start with a 4 that often. In which case, I ask you: of the integers ranging from 0 to 2^32-1, what proportion of them are 4 billion or greater?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the required number of bytes from `os.urandom()`, then convert that to an integer.

```
def gen_seed(num_bytes = 4):
    b = os.urandom(num_bytes)
    return int.from_bytes(b)
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, this seems to yield a uniform dist across the range 2^32 -1.  I wonder if you, or anyone can tell me, about os.urandom(bytes).  Does it extract without replacement the 8 x bytes number of bits from the entropy pool?  Or does it just use a fraction of 8 x bytes entropy bits from the pool?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) explains it. It basically does whatever the `getrandom()` system call or `/dev/urandom` do.

Comment: @betacrash given you mention Linux it might be worth reading: https://www.zx2c4.com/projects/linux-rng-5.17-5.18/ which describes a recent refactor of the code as well as including some history and motivation

Comment: @Barmar:  You answered how to get a uniform number.  We can close this question with that.  But this leads to another question which for which I will make another post.

Comment: @Sam:  Thank you for that reference.  This adds to the next question I will ask in another post.